# tkinter destroy error adding text to canvas

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I am getting an error alloc: invalid block: 047129A8: c0 4 when I add text to the canvas using create_text

Here is a sample program. If the create_text is removed clicking on the rectangle closes the progamme, but after adding text the programme closes but the error message appears and a popup window saying python has stopped working.

If I replace destroy() with quit(), it works fine.
(Python 3.5)

```
import tkinter as TK
class Button():
    def __init__(self):
        self.master = TK.Tk()
        canvas_width = 200
        canvas_height =200
        canvas = TK.Canvas(self.master, width=canvas_width,  height=canvas_height)
        button = canvas.create_rectangle([10,10,110,30],fill='lightgrey')
        canvas.tag_bind(button, "<ButtonPress-1>", self.test) # lambda x: self.action(x,DOWN))  
        canvas.pack()
        canvas_id = canvas.create_text(10, 50, anchor="nw")
        canvas.itemconfig(canvas_id, text="this is the text")
        TK.mainloop()
    def test(self, e):
        print ('Clicked')
        #self.master.quit()
        self.master.destroy()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = Button()
```

Comment: then why don't you use `.quit()`? It is crashing python because the instance of `tkinter` that was dealing with the threads running `self.test` were destroyed part way through where as using `.quit()` gives the system more chance to clean up while closing.

Comment: I don't see why adding create_text should cause this. Without the create_text (and I have tested this on a much larger application) destroy works fine. Yes, of course I could use quit, but when errors occur I like to know why.

Comment: Oh misunderstood what the odd behaviour, just tested it removing the `create_text` and it did same thing on my mac.  In that case forget my earlier comment, I want to know why this happens too!

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem many times, but now I figured out a way. You just have to delete the text before closing the window.

```
import tkinter as TK
class Button():
    def __init__(self):
        self.master = TK.Tk()
        canvas_width = 200
        canvas_height = 200
        self.canvas = TK.Canvas(self.master, width=canvas_width,  height=canvas_height)
        button = self.canvas.create_rectangle([10,10,110,30],fill='lightgrey')
        self.canvas.tag_bind(button, "<ButtonPress-1>", self.test) # lambda x: self.action(x,DOWN))  
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.canvas_id = self.canvas.create_text(10, 50, anchor="nw")
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.canvas_id, text="this is the text")
        TK.mainloop()
    def test(self, e):
        print('Clicked')
        self.canvas.delete(self.canvas_id) #delete the text
        self.master.destroy()              #then close

if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = Button()
```

By the way, I changed `canvas` to `self.canvas` so that I could access it in the 'test' function.

Hope this helps :D

Answer (score 0):

As it was answered, pack the things given by `canvas.create_text()` into `canvas.canvas_texts`(which is a list can be add when running `__init__()` method and after the `canvas` is created.) Then define a method that iterate the `canvas.canvas_texts` and execute command the followings:

```py
for item in self.canvas.canvas_texts:
    self.canvas.delete(item)
```

After that, you should be able to execute [something]`.destroy()`.

Here is a complete example of how to couple with this weird case:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class TheClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.geometry("500x500")

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.window, width=300, height=300)
        self.canvas.canvas_texts = []
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.quitImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("picture.png"))
        self.quitButton = self.canvas.create_image(50, 50, image=self.quitImage)
        self.canvas.tag_bind(self.quitButton, "<Button-1>", self.quitGame)
        self.canvas.canvas_texts.append(self.canvas.create_text(10, 10, text='hello, this is a string of text'))
        print(self.canvas.canvas_texts)     # You can see that it's a number rather than some tkinter object.

    def run(self):
        self.window.mainloop()

    def quitGame(self, event):
        for item in self.canvas.canvas_texts:
            self.canvas.delete(item)   # Important sentence.
        self.window.destroy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    anInstance = TheClass()
    anInstance.run()
```

Hope this is helpful.